# WlanRegisterNotification() causes exception in KernelBase.dll when WlanCloseHandle() is called

Tags: exception, winapi, wlanapi

I use WLAN functions of Windows (see wlanapi.h) for communication with a special measuring device. Every written function from me works without any problems (no thrown exception, no returned error codes).

However after connecting to a WLAN net, I see the following message in output pane of Visual Studio:

> Exception thrown at 0x7733D902 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0x0000000D: The data is invalid.

Sometimes following message appears:

> Exception thrown bei 0x7733D902 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.

These messages appears in debug and release mode.

After some research I found the problem origin at WlanRegisterNotification(). I can reproduce the error with the following code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wlanapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>


// ******************** Debug code for reproducing exception in KernelBase.dll ********************

#pragma comment(lib, "Wlanapi.lib")

static
void WINAPI WlanNotificationCallback(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA Data, PVOID)
{
    if (Data->NotificationSource & WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM)
    {
        switch (Data->NotificationCode)
        {
        case wlan_notification_acm_connection_start:
            std::cout << "WlanNotificationCallback>> Connection establishment has started.\n";
            break;
        case wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete:
            std::cout << "WlanNotificationCallback>> Connection established.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void WLAN_Check()
{
    HANDLE ClientHandle = nullptr;
    DWORD CurVersion = 0;
    DWORD q = 0;

    q = WlanOpenHandle(WLAN_API_VERSION, nullptr, &CurVersion, &ClientHandle);
    if (q != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("WlanOpenHandle failed with error: {}\n", q);
        return;
    }
    q = WlanRegisterNotification(ClientHandle, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM, FALSE, WlanNotificationCallback, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (q != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("WlanRegisterNotification failed with error: {}\n", q);
        return;
    }
    q = WlanRegisterNotification(ClientHandle, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM, FALSE, WlanNotificationCallback, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (q != ERROR_SUCCESS) // Set Breakpoint here
    {
        std::cout << std::format("WlanRegisterNotification failed with error: {}\n", q);
        return;
    }
    q = WlanCloseHandle(ClientHandle, nullptr);
    if (q != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("WlanCloseHandle failed with error: {}\n", q);
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    WLAN_Check();
    return 0;
}
```

If I set breakpoint to last `WlanRegisterNotification()` and do one debugging step, above message appear.

Is there a bug in my code?

Comment: Are the exceptions actually escaping the API into your code? If not, then don't worry about them, the API is handling them internally.  The debugger simply sees exceptions before application code does.

Comment: No exception is escaping. So its OK. Thank you.